# Pins that I used in LCD are not working as OUTPUT for LED

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am running out of pins. I used the pin that I use in LCD as output for a LED however the led is not turning off its always even my code is like this

```
void setup() {
    lcd.begin(20, 4);

    pinMode(7 , OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(7, low);
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you connect a led to pin 7 and what else is in your sketch. What you show requires a definition of `lcd`, `low` and the function `void loop()`.

Comment: I wrote this a while ago: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/06/14/when-14-pins-is-not-enough/. Hopefully it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Plug off the LCD for a while to see whether your led blinking program is correct.

Anyway, you can't use the same pin for different functions, it's good chance that they will

- disturb each other (say, the led will flash silly when you send something to the LCD),
- kick out each other (as we see it in your case).